MailChimp's "GET /lists/{list_id}/segments" doesnt include "static_segments"
I have added a segment using the API "POST /lists/{list_id}/segments" to MailChimp
This segment is not the normal kind. I used the parameter "static_segment" to enter in a list of emails instead of normal conditions.
In order to update it, i need the ID of the segments. So I try and call "GET /lists/{list_id}/segments" and it gives me everything but the static_segments
Is there a parameter for static segments? If I have the name of the segment, how do I get the ID?
Below is my call:
try:
    client = MailchimpMarketing.Client()
    client.set_config({
        "api_key": MAILCHIMP_API_KEY,
        "server": MAILCHIMP_SERVER_PREFIX
    })

    response = client.lists.list_segments(MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID, type="static")
    segments = response['segments']
    for segment in segments:
        print(f"Name: {segment['name']}, ID: {segment['id']}")
except ApiClientError as error:
    print(f"An exception occurred: {error.text}")

I've tried with and without the parameter "type" and i get the same thing; A list of all the segments except the static ones
